Invalid Project field in Pig FOREACH
I have a txt input consists of bigrams, year, count, volume_count, and page_count.
The task is to find out the most common bigrams for each year, and if there is a tie, I need to store all bigrams which has the maximum count.
Here is the code:
-- Load the dataset
data = LOAD '/user/pengzhao/test_set_1.txt'
    USING PigStorage('\t')
    AS (bigram:chararray, year:int, count:int, volume_count:int, page_count:int);

-- Group the data by year
grouped_by_year = GROUP data BY year;

-- Find the most common bigram for each year and handle ties
most_common_bigram_each_year = FOREACH grouped_by_year {
    -- 'data' here refers to all entries from the current year being processed
    -- Find the maximum count for this particular group (year)
    max_count = MAX(data.count);

    -- Filter the bigrams in this group that have the max count
    tied_bigrams = FILTER data BY count == max_count;

    -- Generate the result with year, bigram, and count
    GENERATE group AS year, FLATTEN(tied_bigrams.bigram) AS bigram, FLATTEN(tied_bigrams.count) AS count;
}

-- Store the result into an output directory on HDFS
STORE most_common_bigram_each_year INTO '/user/pengzhao/c4_t1_output' USING PigStorage('\t');


I keep getting the failure that:
19960 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1000: <file s3://aws-logs-471112767724-us-east-1/elasticmapreduce/program/TheMostCommonEachYear.txt, line 20, column 24> Invalid field reference. Referenced field [count] does not exist in schema: .
The line 20 is:     max_count = MAX(data.count);
I don't think the logic has any problems, it's my first time using Pig, may someone help me?
I tried to dump the grouped data and they are nice, there must be something wrong inside the FOREACH operation.
